# Python ignores dash on replace method

Tags: python

I have the following code in python to remove some dashes from a string, all other replaces parameters works well but the dash. I've tried with the replace method and with Regex, but none of them worked.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4  import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import urllib.request
import re

with urllib.request.urlopen("http://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/dados/resultados/comercio-exterior/importacoes-de-produtos-dos-capitulos-01-a-99-da-ncm") as url:
    s = url.read()
soup = Soup(s,  "html.parser")

tables = soup.findAll("table")
for table in tables:
     if table.findParent("table") is None:
         replaced = (table.find("th").find("span").text.replace("-",""))
         print(replaced)
```

Comment: What is the value of `table.find("th").find("span").text` where it fails ?

Comment: There is a lot of tables, some examples are:

Capítulo 22 - Bebidas, líquidos alcoólicos e vinagres

Capítulo 28 - Produtos químicos inorgânicos; compostos inorgânicos ou orgânicos de metais preciosos, de elementos

Comment: There are more than 1 type of dash. https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pd/list.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "dash" in phrases such as `Capítulo 22 – Bebidas, líquidos alcoólicos e vinagres` is not a simple dash – officially a ["hyphen-minus"](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002d/index.htm) – at all. It is an unrelated character with the Unicode U+2013, the [en dash](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm).

Add it to the line that removes the hyphen; you can rewrite it to use a regex, or simply tack it on to the end:

```
replaced = (table.find("th").find("span").text.replace("-","").replace("\u2013",""))
```

after which you get your lines displayed as

```
Capítulo 22  Bebidas, líquidos alcoólicos e vinagres
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity I copied and pasted that sentence in a file, then did hexdump on it, and it said that that character in hexadecimal was 0x80 0xe2 . How did you get the representation `U+2013` ?

Comment: Thank you very much @usr2564301 and Johnny Mopp I was going crazy! Tricky "hyphen"

Comment: @ChatterOne: if you click the link to `en dash`, you can see that the UTF8 representation is `UTF-8 (hex) 0xE2 0x80 0x93`; close enough to what you saw.